# How to serialize derived class by pointer to base class? Derived::serialize not called

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, polymorphism

I am attempting to make derived class serializable by boost serialization using pointer to base class.

Base::serialization called. Derived::serialization not called.

What did I do wrong?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>

struct Base
{
    int x;
    Base() { x = 0; }
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & x;
    }
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)

struct Derived : Base
{
    int y;
    Derived() { x = 1; y = 2; }
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived derived;
    Base *basePtr = &derived;

    std::string s;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);

    oa << *basePtr;
}
```

Comment: Edited. Still does not work.

Comment: If you talk about void serialize: member function templates cannot be virtual.

Comment: Indeed, making the types involved virtual is mandatory to allow RTTI (note that Boost Any in stopped requiring RTTI in boost 1.57.0, perhaps in the future such a technique could be adopted for Boost Serialization too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're not serializing through a pointer, fix it:

```
oa << basePtr;
```

Secondly, you need to register derived types:

```
oa.register_type<Derived>();
```

Or, inside the serialize function:

```
ar.template register_type<Derived>();
```

You might_ also want to look at registering class information for serialization: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/serialization/doc/special.html#export

---

**UPDATE** To the comment/edited question:

Your question code serializes a `Base*` and deserializes a `Derived`. The types are unrelated, this could never work. They need to be identical.

Also, register the Derived type reading the input archive.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c39a351600c36c7)</kbd>**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/assume_abstract.hpp>

struct Derived;

struct Base
{
    int x;
    Base() { x = 0; }
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar.template register_type<Derived>();
        ar & x;
    }
};

BOOST_SERIALIZATION_ASSUME_ABSTRACT(Base)

struct Derived : Base
{
    int y;
    Derived() { x = 1; y = 2; }
    virtual ~Derived() {}

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
        ar & y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    {
        Derived derived;
        Base *basePtr = &derived;

        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss);
        oa.register_type<Derived>();

        oa << basePtr;
        ss.flush();
    }

    {
        boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(ss);
        ia.register_type<Derived>();

        Base *basePtr = nullptr;

        ia >> basePtr;
        std::cout << "basePtr->x = " << basePtr->x << "\n";
        if (Derived* derivedPtr = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(basePtr))
            std::cout << "derivedPtr->y = " << derivedPtr->y << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Input does not work. Can you help me? Question edited.

Comment: WAIT A SECOND. Did [you just **unaccept** this answer](http://i.imgur.com/I5bqkFK.png), just to ask /a different question/? You should just post a new question. This is a really dorky move if you ask me.